# power up bluetooth speaker with voice command (Megaboom3)

Tags: android, typescript, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, home-assistant

i am trying to make a google assistant task chain.

1 power on bluetooth.
2 wait two seconds
3 use the app Boom switch to power up two paired Megaboom 3.
4 set media volume to 30%.
5 start Spotify playlist.

the 3rd step is my problem.

the app "Boom switch" is not in google home assistant shortcuts.
the app itself can create widgets/shortcuts to homescreen which can activate 1 speaker at a time with a click/tab.

voice trigger "hey google lets party"

action "activate bluetooth"
wait 2 seconds

[open boom switch speaker_one
wait 2 seconds
open boom switch speaker_two]  <---[need correct phrasing set up]

set media_volume to 30%

open spotify playlist

i hope you can solve this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I believe this question would fit better at the [Android Enthusiast StackExchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/)